# How can I reference an XML file in my Visual Studio 2012 project as a data source in my project code?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

My project includes a combo box with a list of databases for the user to select. The selection determines which database will be contacted later on.

Since databases have odd names, I'd like to give each an intelligible designation to be shown in the combo box's Display Value, with the actual database name hidden in the Value Member property (ie, "Database 1" for "XYZprojDB123"). So I put together an XML file with Display Value / Value Member pairs and added it to my project in Visual Studio, but now I can't link to it in my code. Just writing

```
XDocument dbList = XDocument.Load("Databases.xml");
```

doesn't work.

This is a Windows application, so I'll want to include this XML file for distribution when I publish. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: I'd probably do it in your config file rather than a separate XML file - that way you don't have to do anything special. You can do it in appSettings, or you can build your own section and types.

Answer (score 5):

If the XML file has been added to your project:

- Right click on your XML file in the solution explorer and click **Properties**
- change **Build Action** to `None`
- change **Copy to output directory** to `Copy if newer`

Once you do that, your xml file will be copied to your project's local directory, and `XDocument dbList = XDocument.Load("Databases.xml");` should work.

Comment: I originally marked this as the answer, but I had to unmark it because I've discovered the xml file isn't being included when I publish the application and install it on a client machine. It's only working during debugging.

Comment: @bmurrell30 can't you just copy it manually, or write your own publish script?

Comment: @SamIam thank you for your answer. I have a further question: what does changing the build action to 'none' actually do and why is it different from the other options listed?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon That just means it doesn't attempt to do anything with the file when you build.  Since you're just copying the file over, you don't need a build action.